# How to call php through c# using API?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a php website through API, which gives the below `Error 403`.
Kindly check my code below. If anyone has a solution kindly help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your request is true, but the website detects that an application tries to get to website and blocks the request to stop scrapping website.
If you want to pass the server filter, I think you should check a request to this website from a browser and then add the browser headers to your request so the server assume it as a browser and will accept it.